# calculate mean of multidimensional array using indices and masking array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

```
m =  np.array([[[0.4,0.5],[0.2,0.3]], [[0.8,0.1],[0.7,0.9]]])
id = np.array([[[1,2],[2,3]], [[3,1],[3,2]]])
mask = np.array([[[0,1],[1,0]], [[1,1],[1,1]]])
```

I'd like to calculate the mean of `m` for each index in `id`, and only for nonzero elements in `mask`.

For example for `id==3`, that would be the mean of `[0.8,0.7]`.

I thought `np.ma.masked_array.mean` would do the trick but this does not give me the expected output

```
 >> np.ma.masked_array(m[id==3],mask=mask[id==3]).mean()
    0.29999999
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple array indexing should work:

```
import numpy as np

m =  np.array([[[0.4,0.5],[0.2,0.3]], [[0.8,0.1],[0.7,0.9]]])
my_id = np.array([[[1,2],[2,3]], [[3,1],[3,2]]])
mask = np.array([[[0,1],[1,0]], [[1,1],[1,1]]])

print(m[(mask != 0) & (my_id == 3)])          # [0.8 0.7]
print(m[(mask != 0) & (my_id == 3)].mean())   # 0.75
```

Also, `id` is a built-in function, so don't name a variable that. It will shadow the built-in.

Answer (score 2):

Apply the mask to both `m` and `id_` and then use `np.bincount`

```
m =  np.array([[[0.4,0.5],[0.2,0.3]], [[0.8,0.1],[0.7,0.9]]])
id_ = np.array([[[1,2],[2,3]], [[3,1],[3,2]]])
mask = np.array([[[0,1],[1,0]], [[1,1],[1,1]]])

mask = mask.astype(bool)
mm, idm = m[mask], id_[mask]
result = np.bincount(idm, mm)/np.bincount(idm)

result
# array([       nan, 0.1       , 0.53333333, 0.75      ])
```

`result` contains all the means, for example `result[3]` is the mean for `id_` 3.

Note: your approach does not work because by convention in a masked array the mask specifies the *missing* not the valid data, in other words you'd have to invert the mask.